# How do you make a div show when vimeo video is finished?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm really new to JS, and can't figure out these event listeners on Vimeo. Basically I need a div, below the video, to be hidden while the video plays, and appear when the video finishes. Please help, as I have no idea where to start. I've tried everything.

This is what I have so far, but no luck:

```
<div style="margin-left:2%;" >  
        <iframe id="flash" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/50234176?api=1&amp&portrait=0&byline=0&autoplay=1&title=0;player_id=player_1" width="760" height="460" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="hello" >hello</div>
<script>
$('#hello').hide();

var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
    player = $f(iframe),

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
  player.addEvent('finish', function(){
    $('#hello').show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, your div can be hidden by using a simple CSS `display:none`, or calling `$('#yourDivID').hide();`

So, to show your div again when the video is finished, try this way:

```
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
  player.addEvent('finish', function(){
    $('#yourDivID').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what your writing but not having much luck

Comment: Change the id of your iframe to player1, and test again

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks. Now it hides the div, which is great. But no luck no showing it again

Comment: Are you including the Froogaloop.js script in your html? If don't, create a script locally named froogaloop.js in the same directory of your html, copy the code from https://raw.github.com/vimeo/player-api/master/javascript/froogaloop.js. Remove the first line (the alert). And include it with <script src="froogaloop.js"></script>.